# What is a better way of finding indices and applying different operations on a vector/matrix?

Tags: r, performance, conditional-statements

I need a short piece of code to apply different conditions on a vector. I need the code to be efficient, in terms of computational complexity, too. Here is an example of my problem:

Suppose I have a vector/matrix **temp** and I want to apply the following two conditions on it:

- Find the indices where the value is < 0
- Find the indices where the value is < -10

I can find the indices using the following piece of code:

```
index1 = temp[, 3] < 0
index2 = temp[, 3] < -10
```

Then I want to apply different operations for each of these conditions. For instance, I want to divide all values below -10 by 100, and divide the values between -10 to 0 by 10. I can do it using the following piece of code:

```
temp[index1, 3] = temp[index1, 3] / 10
temp[index2, 3] = temp[index2, 3] / 100
```

I was wondering, is the a better and more efficient way of applying different operations given several conditions on a vector/matrix?

**I just realized that there is a bug in my code**

The bug is since I am not able to find the values where both conditions are met at the same time (e.g. values more than -10 and less than 0), I am dividing the values two times. This is not the result I want. Could you please help me fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty sure the first part is a duplicate: Search more diligently and use terms 'which' and 'index'. Second part is addressed by using the "[" function with a two column matrix. There is a description of this in the help page for "[" which would be useful to study repeatedly as you progress in learning R.

Comment: @Amir Anyway I tried a solution before it was marked as duplicate.  Here it is `set.seed(42); temp <- sample(-30:30, 50, replace=TRUE); temp/c(100, 10, 1)[cut(temp,breaks=c(-Inf, -10, 0, Inf), labels=FALSE)]`

Comment: @akrun: Very similar to a thought I had (after marking as duplicate) that one could use `findInterval` to select from a set of values. But I'm pretty sure that would be a duplicate if I did the requisite searching.

Comment: @BondedDust  It is okay that it was marked as duplicate.  I pasted the code in case the OP didn't find it